# SIGSEV error when writing to and reading from a file

Tags: c, runtime-error

I am writing code to read and write a text file. But when I run my code, I'm getting a SIGSEGV run-time error. I need help figuring out what is wrong with the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    /*Variable for writing to file */
    char *name[] = {"Raju", "Nayan", "Hanif"};
    char *id[] = {"100", "101", "102"};
    float cgpa[] = {3.50, 5.00, 4.00};
    /*Variable for reading from file*/
    char *getname, *getid;
    float getcgpa;
    int i;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("f:\\raju.nog", "w"); /*Create new file */
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        fprintf(fp, "%-10s%-10s%-1.2f\n", name[i], id[i], cgpa[i]); /*write to file*/
    }
    fclose(fp);
    /*read from file and print to screen*/
    fp = fopen("f:\\raju.nog", "r");
    while(fscanf(fp, "%s %s %f", &getname, &getid, &getcgpa) != EOF){
        printf("%-10s%-10s%-1.2f\n", getname, getid, getcgpa);
    }

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: You arrays have 3 elements, but in `fprintf` you try to access their 4th and 5th elements

Comment: Using tools like`gdb` and `valgrind` will help you quickly and accurately find these types of coding mistakes.

Comment: If you find any of the answers helpful, you may upvote them and "accept" the one that helps you the most. That is how people are awarded for helping others around here.

Comment: Please show what you have done to debug your own code before you ask other people to debug it for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The arrays:

```
char *name[] = {"Raju", "Nayan", "Hanif"};
char *id[] = {"100", "101", "102"};
float cgpa[] = {3.50, 5.00, 4.00};
```

declare 3 elements but

```
for(i=0; i<5; i++){
    fprintf(fp, "%-10s%-10s%-1.2f\n", name[i], id[i], cgpa[i]); /*write to file*/
}
```

is trying to iterate over 5, thus overrunning the bounds of the arrays.

Answer (score 5):

Your code has a few problems:

- You are writing 5 elements of each variable to your file, but each variable only has three elements - causing a [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)
- getname, getid variables are only pointers, no storage for them

To find these errors you should be able to step through with your debugger.

Here is code that works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    /*Variable for writing to file */
    char *name[] = {"Raju", "Nayan", "Hanif"};
    char *id[] = {"100", "101", "102"};
    float cgpa[] = {3.50, 5.00, 4.00};
    /*Variable for reading from file*/

    // need storage space
    char getname[40], getid[40];
    float getcgpa;
    int i;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("raju.nog", "w"); /*Create new file */

    // Only 3 elements
    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
        fprintf(fp, "%-10s%-10s%-1.2f\n", name[i], id[i], cgpa[i]); /*write to file*/
    }
    fclose(fp);
    /*read from file and print to screen*/
    fp = fopen("raju.nog", "r");
    while(fscanf(fp, "%s %s %f", &getname, &getid, &getcgpa) != EOF){
        printf("%-10s%-10s%-1.2f\n", getname, getid, getcgpa);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

If you have access to gdb you could have found the first problem, and then the second problem. Here is a log of my GDB session pointing out the line causing the first error in your code:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/jrn/SO/a.out 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x005cc35e in vfprintf () from /lib/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x005cc35e in vfprintf () from /lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x005d33cf in fprintf () from /lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x08048565 in main () at sowrong.c:15
(gdb) list
1   #include <stdio.h>
2   #include <stdlib.h>
3   int main(){
4       /*Variable for writing to file */
5       char *name[] = {"Raju", "Nayan", "Hanif"};
6       char *id[] = {"100", "101", "102"};
7       float cgpa[] = {3.50, 5.00, 4.00};
8       /*Variable for reading from file*/
9       char *getname, *getid;
10      float getcgpa;
(gdb) list
11      int i;
12      FILE *fp;
13      fp = fopen("f:\\raju.nog", "w"); /*Create new file */
14      for(i=0; i<5; i++){
15          fprintf(fp, "%-10s%-10s%-1.2f\n", name[i], id[i], cgpa[i]); /*write to file*/
16      }
17      fclose(fp);
18      /*read from file and print to screen*/
19      fp = fopen("f:\\raju.nog", "r");
20      while(fscanf(fp, "%s %s %f", &getname, &getid, &getcgpa) != EOF){
(gdb) list
21          printf("%-10s%-10s%-1.2f\n", getname, getid, getcgpa);
22      }
23  }
```

Notice the line: `#2  0x08048565 in main () at sowrong.c:15`  
This tells you the segfault happened on line 15. After that you can list the file to see the line.

So now after fixing line 15, you compile your program again and run it through GDB to find the second problem. Here is the log of my GDB session:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/jrn/SO/a.out 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x005cc35e in vfprintf () from /lib/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x005cc35e in vfprintf () from /lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x005d3410 in printf () from /lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x080485be in main () at sowrong.c:21
(gdb) list
1   #include <stdio.h>
2   #include <stdlib.h>
3   int main(){
4       /*Variable for writing to file */
5       char *name[] = {"Raju", "Nayan", "Hanif"};
6       char *id[] = {"100", "101", "102"};
7       float cgpa[] = {3.50, 5.00, 4.00};
8       /*Variable for reading from file*/
9       char *getname, *getid;
10      float getcgpa;
(gdb) list
11      int i;
12      FILE *fp;
13      fp = fopen("f:\\raju.nog", "w"); /*Create new file */
14      for(i=0; i<3; i++){
15          fprintf(fp, "%-10s%-10s%-1.2f\n", name[i], id[i], cgpa[i]); /*write to file*/
16      }
17      fclose(fp);
18      /*read from file and print to screen*/
19      fp = fopen("f:\\raju.nog", "r");
20      while(fscanf(fp, "%s %s %f", &getname, &getid, &getcgpa) != EOF){
(gdb) list
21          printf("%-10s%-10s%-1.2f\n", getname, getid, getcgpa);
22      }
23  }
```

Again notice the line: `#2  0x080485be in main () at sowrong.c:21`   
A second SEGFAULT, because your variables are just pointers with no storage space.

Answer (score 3):

you haven't malloc memory for

```
 char *getname, *getid;
```

Answer (score 3):

`char *getname, *getid;` only allocates pointers, not memory to store the strings.  You need something like:

```
char getname[11];
char getid[11];
```

I have guessed the sizes from your `printf` statement, but you probably want larger arrays than those.

Answer (score 2):

Your for loop counter goes from 0 to 4, but you arrays `name`, `id` and `cgpa` have only 3 elements: so you are going out of array boundaries.